# Access Token is always null. Using flutter_facebook_login 3.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart

**Anybody here to help? Thanks**
The access token return null. I am using flutter_facebook_login 3.0.0 and flutter version `Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8 • channel stable` and dart 2.7.0

```
  Future loginWithFacebook() async {
    FacebookLogin facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult =
        await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
    debugPrint(facebookLoginResult.status.toString());
    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print("Logged In");
        final accessToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token;
        final facebookAuthCred =
            FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: accessToken);
        final fbuser =
            await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCred);
        final user = fbuser.user;
        return user != null;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("Cancelled");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        final accessToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token;
        debugPrint(accessToken.toString());
        print("error");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post the result of the `debugPrint`?

Comment: unfortunately i am unable to reproduce the error but it was `there is no 'getter' for token`. and the debugPrint was `null`.

Comment: I decided to use `flutter_facebook_auth: ^0.1.1` and that worked. Then i switched back to `flutter_facebook_login 3.0.0` and it just worked. I don't understand the magic that just happened.